# Get id of image from url to insert into another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the PHP SQL tutorial, but can't figure out how to get the id from the url
This is the index file line:

```
echo "<a href='addTagToImg.php?id=" . $row['img_id'] . "' title='Created tag' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tags'></span></a>";
```

row id:
http://localhost/ImgDB/addTagToImg.php?id=3

The table I want to insert to has the columns imgkeywords_id,img_id,keyword_id

The point is to only use input for keyword_id

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$img_id = $keyword_id = "";
$img_id_err = $keyword_id_err = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    img_id = trim($_POST["img_id"])

    // Get hidden input value
    $input_keyword_id = trim($_POST["keyword_id"]);
    if (empty($input_keyword_id)) {
        $keyword_id_err = "Please enter an name.";
    } else {
        $keyword_id = $input_keyword_id;
   }



    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if (empty($keyword_id_err) && empty($img_id)) {

        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO imgkeywords (img_id,keyword_id) VALUES (?,?)";

        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_img_id, $param_keyword_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_keyword_id = $keyword_id;
            $param_img_id = $img_id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "HERE!!Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}

?>

          <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($keyword_id_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                  <label>Tag ID</label>
                  <input type="text" name="keyword_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $keyword_id; ?>">
                  <span class="help-block"><?php echo $keyword_id_err; ?></span>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
              <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
          </form>
```

So basically I get an id of an image in another table but want to insert that id into another table

Answer (score 2):

you dont need `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` because once you entered the php file using `<a href=` it means that you are doing a `GET` request. and on your URL: the variable name for `id=3`, you can access the value using `$_GET["id"]`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I figured it out. I got it to work by changing the form action.
`
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("addTagToImg.php?id=" . $img_id) ?>" method="POST">
`

The main problem was then i submitted the id was gone, so instead of $_SERVER... i changed it to the above and it finally worked

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to get the id and then change

```
<?php

$img_id = $_GET['id'];
...


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
...

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("addTagToImg.php?id=" . $img_id) ?>" method="POST">
  ...
```